# How to utilize the object updated by first child class into parent class into second child class

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns

I have a use case related to spring applications.
I have 2 child classes consider it as

```
@Component
public class OhioServiceCenter extends TeslaServiceCenter
@Component
public class FloridaServiceCenter extends TeslaServiceCenter
```

Now as we can see we have 2 child classes both of which are extending one parent abstract class.
Now I have one bean which I am auto-wiring into both of the child classes which returns me an inventory, you can consider it a list of items. Let's for the sake of consideration say this bean is `Tesla` and have one method in `Tesla` called `getCars` this method returns me a `List<Car>`. Now both of the the child classes implmenting a parent abstract methods called `doService` both of them have different implementations. But both of them have same dependency on the `List<Cars`.

Now as per my usecase. I don't want both of the child classes holding the `List<Cars` because its a memory problem both of the child classes holding same inventory is memeory wastage.(**NOTE - that `getCars` will return new List everytime means to say there content will be same but in memory there will be new list created everytime and that can't be changed**).
What I expect is that parent class should hold the inventory and then both of the child class should be able to operate over it .

**APPROACHES I TRIED**

1. I tried to kept the parent class as an abstract class and have abstract method `getCars` which is being implemented by both the child classes. My thinking was I could autowire the `Tesla` object in child classes and could maintain a inventory in abstract class but the problem is for both of the child classes there are different memories are allocated for parent classes too so even if first child class could update the parent object second wont be able to access it.
2. Also one another problem is abstract classes can't autowire things so I can't also controll the part of getting inventory directly into abstract class
3. I tried to create parent class as a normal class  but then the problem is `doService`
   can't be abstracted as java don't allows the abstract method in normal classes

**PROBLEM IN SHORT SUMMARY**
I want 2 child classes to be able to share the same memory references of a parent class so that both the parent classes could access and update the same object in parent class.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold the reference in the parent class and inject it from the Spring context from the child class. Would something like this work?

```java
abstract class TeslaServiceCenter {
    private final Tesla tesla;

    protected TeslaServiceCenter(Tesla tesla) {
        this.tesla = tesla;
    }
}

@Component
class OhioServiceCenter extends TeslaServiceCenter {
    public OhioServiceCenter(Tesla tesla) {
        super(tesla);
    }
}

@Component
class FloridaServiceCenter extends TeslaServiceCenter {
    public FloridaServiceCenter(Tesla tesla) {
        super(tesla);
    }
}
```

By the way, if Tesla is defined as a bean in the context and it has singleton scope (which is configured by default, if you don't change it), you'll have the same Tesla instance when you autowire in different components - essentially, it doesn't have to be in the parent class.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Emanuel.
But there are still few problems, as I mentioned `Tesla` class has a method called `getCars` which returns a list of cars every time. So even if I try the approach you suggested of using the `super` to populate the parent abstract class variable, that will not help us out. Because whenever we create a child class bean( or object ) then parent abstract class's unique refference created. Means for both `OhioServiceCenter` and `FloridaServiceCenter` there are unique memory reference created for `TeslaServiceCenter`. So that aproach will not help us out here

Comment: I was also in the same idea that using abstract class if there are 2 child classes they will point to same parent variables. But after practically trying this and searching about it a bit, I came to know that everytime there are unique refference create for abstact classes too .

Comment: how often is this list changing? can you use some caching maybe?

Comment: I am sorry I think I am not able to explain this point here. Let me reiterate. How frequently the list changes is not the issue. The issue which I am trying to solve is, how 2 child classes can have the same shared memory. Previously my understanding was abstract class objects share the same memory but that was incorrect. So my question exactly is how can we achieve a process where a parent class can have both abstract and generic methods, so that if any child updates any object in the parent class then all the children have access to it.
Any code which can solve this can help us